# Redirect all access on IP address to domain name need to click proceed to redirect

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I have this config in my apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName default

    <Location />
        Redirect / https://domain.name
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

     ServerName default
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem
     SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire

    <Location />
        Redirect / https://domain.name
    </Location>

     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I access IP_ADDRESS or http://IP_ADDRESS on browser it redirects to https://domain.name
But when I try to access https://IP_ADDRESS it redirects to the page where you need to click proceed when you have a self signed cert. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://IP_ADDRESS it redirects to the page where you need to click proceed when you have a self signed cert.

That is not exactly a "*redirect*", but a warning page that gets generated by your webbrowser.

The cause is the same though as with a self-signed certificate: your web server can't provide a valid SSL certificate for address you entered in the address bar of your web browser, i.e. there is no valid certificate offered by your webserver that contains your IP-address. Your typical SSL certificate is only valid for one or more hostnames, `www.example.com` , `example.net`  or maybe a wildcard `*.example.com` and not for bare IP-addresses.

The simple solution for that is:

- don't enter https://IP_ADDRESS in your address bar, use your domainname

The alternative would be to get a  valid certificate issued for your IP-address.  Normal visitors to your website will never enter an IP-address to visit your site though and in almost all cases there is no business need to do so.

Comment: thank you Rob for this answer. is this not a security vulnerability?

Comment: Unless you're in the habit to configure applications and instruct users to connect to the bare IP-address, there is no security issue.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. A way to redirect http[s]://IP_ADDRESS traffic is needed so that nobody can bypass the secure requirement, period.
"Don't do that" isn't sufficient.